# Bootstrap viewports not recognized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap, I'm trying to show divs A and B stacked on extra small devices and displayed in one line on small devices and above. (just like in this example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal)

However, the divs are not stacked on extra small devices (using Firefox ESR 52.4), but stay the same across all device sizes.

Any hint about what I am missing would be great:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap related files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrapcss/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrapjs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/workarounds/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        A
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8 hidden-xs-down"
           style="text-align:right">
        B
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /.row-->
(...)
```

There are other bootstrap elements further down on the page which work, but the layout instructions do not. I have checked that all related js and css files are available, they all return status 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap grid classes are specific to certain screen sizes and can be used together. (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) If you want the divs in the row to stack on extra-small (xs) give them the class `col-12` to force the columns to take the full width of the row on devices smaller than 576px wide.